# Is it possible to connect Apache Kafka to Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-sql-database, apache-kafka-connect

I have an application to develop where it is required to connect Azure SQL DB to Apache Kafka. 
Azure DB----> SOURCE CONNECTOR --->Kafka Topic. 
Is there any such connector available? If not, how else can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Azure SQL DB supports JDBC you can use the [JDBC Source connector](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-jdbc/) ([deep dive here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector))

I've not tried it but you might want to see if the SQL Server log-based CDC options work too, available as Kafka Connect connectors:

- [kafka-connect-cdc-microsoft-sql](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-cdc-microsoft-sql/)
- [Debezium](http://debezium.io) (support for SQL Server added in 0.9)

The difference between query-based (JDBC) capture and log-based CDC is explained in [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/no-more-silos-how-to-integrate-your-databases-with-apache-kafka-and-cdc).

Comment: JDBC yes.  And per the docs that connector actually uses Change Tracking, which _is_ available in Azure SQL Database.  Not the log-based Change Data Capture, which is not.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft do you have more details/reference I can read? The JDBC connector can only poll via query, so not every record state change is guaranteed to be captured (unlike log-based CDC). Thanks.

Comment: Change Tracking wont capture every state change, it just tracks which rows have been inserted/update/deleted since the last time you checked.  "This connector utilizes the Change Tracking feature available in most versions of SQL Server." - https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-cdc-mssql/

Comment: SQL Server on Azure recently added support for CDC, and they also provide an example showing how to use this with Debezium. I have updated the [Debezium documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/nightly/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-on-azure) accordingly. See [this post](https://debezium.io/blog/2018/07/19/advantages-of-log-based-change-data-capture/) to learn more about the advantages of log-based CDC over query-based approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I found a connector **Fivetran** can do that.
I haven't try it but I think you can learn from it.

Reference: [Connect Azure SQL Database and apache-kafka data with Fivetran](https://fivetran.com/directory/microsoft-azure-sql-database/apache-kafka).

Documentation: [Fivetran Documentation](https://fivetran.com/docs/getting-started).

Hope this can be useful for you.